# The nasty definition of limit.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I attached two pictures to show these question.
I finished these matching problems, but I am not sure whether my answers are right or wrong:

- (a),(b) match (vii)
- (d) match (ii) [prove: if $\delta = 0$, it implies that $0 <|x-c|\leq \delta$, which means no x can satisfy the condition]
- (h) match (vi)
- (c) match (iv) [prove: if $\epsilon=0$, it implies that $f(x)=L$. So I matched (c) to (iv).
- (b) and (e) match (i)
- (f) match (vii)
- (h) match (v) [I am very not sure about this one, because I have no idea about its difference between (h) and (g).

Really appreciate for these mathematicians who check my works!

[image]

[image]

Comment: a,b does not satisfy (vii) also c does not satisfy (iv) and e,b does not satisfy (i).

Comment: $g$ is the same as the definition of the limit, they just replace $\delta$ with $\varepsilon$... also $h$ does not satisfy (v). The rest is ok.

Comment: Regarding (c), if $\epsilon = 0$, then $|f(x) - L| < 0$, which is impossible. Regarding (d), if we take $\delta = 0$ then every function vacuously satisfies the implication.

Comment: if we take \delta equal 0, why it work? I think 0 < |x-c| < 0 is not possible. Can you explain it why I am wrong? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is an exercise in symbol shunting and with some patience one can see that $(g) $ fits the definition of limit. But symbol shunting can not help one understand that $(e) $ is also a valid definition of limit. Therefore it is best to have an understanding of the definition of limit rather than its exact formulation in terms of mathematical symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a)  How is it different?

It says $|x-c|<\delta \implies cdots$ where all the others say $0<|x-c|<\delta \implies \cdots$

What is the implication?

$x = c \implies f(x) = L$  (iv)

b)  How is it different?
It says $\cdots 0<|f(x) - L|<\epsilon$

What is the implication?

$f(x) \ne L$ for all $x$ in a neighborhood of $c$ (v)

g) is the standard definition with $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ swapped at every place.

h) $\exists \delta > 0, \forall \epsilon: 0<|x-c|<\delta \implies |f(x) - L|<\epsilon$

You chose the interval first, and then say that $f(x)$ is arbitrarily close to $L$ for every $x$ in the interval.

$f(x)$ is constant for some interval.

Comment: (c) is in fact impossible; taking $\epsilon = 0$ we would need to exhibit a $\delta > 0$ such that $0 < |x-c| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - L| < 0$. The latter inequality cannot occur.

Comment: I will strike that line while I think about that.

Comment: how a) implies that x=c implies f(x)=L? It did not say \epsilon and \delta can equal 0.